# R : ggplotを使用した散布図の色分けについて

Tags: r, ggplot2

次の様なデータResを使用した場合にRegの値で任意に色分けした散布図を作成したいです。
   Reg    h    w    sex
1   1    180   60   M
2   2    155   50   F
3   3    160   55   F
4   2    170   65   M
....

```
base <- ggplot(Res, aes(x = h, y = w, colour = Reg))
points <- base + geom_point(size = 5)
plot(points)
```

このままの実行ではRegの値での色分けはされるのですが、
青系色の濃淡でのみ分けられている状態です。
より明確に、赤や緑等に分けて表示したいのですが、
どのように書けば良いのでしょうか。教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございました。無事に色分けして表示することが可能となりました。

Answer (score 1):

おそらくは，色分けに使用しているRegという変数が数値データ(連続量)として扱われているために，グラデーションの濃淡として色分けされるのだと思います。

なので，この変数をfactor型に変換すれば個別に色を指定できるようになるかと思います:

```
library(ggplot2)

## 説明用データセット作成
Res <- data.frame(
  Reg = sample(1:3, 50, replace = TRUE),
  h = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 165, sd = 10),
  w = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 55, sd = 10)
)

## 色分けに使う変数をfactor型に
Res$Reg <- as.factor(Res$Reg)

## 後は同一の記述でOK
base <- ggplot(Res, aes(x = h, y = w, colour = Reg))
points <- base + geom_point(size = 5)
plot(points)

## 個別に色を指定も可能

change_colors <- points + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
plot(change_colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Res$Reg <- factor(Res$Reg)

色が気に入らなければ、

scale_color_manual(values = c("hoge", "hoge"))

とするなど。